# Windows Server 2008 R2 time slice size?

Tags: multithreading, windows-server-2008-r2

How big is time slice for a thread to run in W2008R2 ?

Comment: Why do people want to close this question?

Comment: because majority or people afraid of things they don't know ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the Russinovich book the timeslice or quantum takes 12 x clock ticks on server calculated in CPU cycles (OS calculates how many CPU cycles in one tick and then count them excluding interruprts, switches etc).

I run with clockres = 1ms, so the quantum on my box is about 12ms.

Comment: Is that "ms" as in milliseconds, or "ms" as in microseconds?

Comment: uhm...just in case someone finds this thread...after 3 years...
ms = "milliseconds"
us or my/s or (greek U) = "microseconds"